# Detect if context is from activity or adapter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context, onactivityresult

Is there any ability to detect if context is from activity or adapter?

It's essential to detect if we can do

```
(Activity(context)).startActivityForResult(..) ...
```

Comment: What do you mean "context from adapter"? Activity is context, but adapter isn't context. When you creating adapter you pass context to it. What context you passing?

Comment: Yep, from documentation: "Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc." . But if it's global why do we need to do (Activity(context)), instead of just calling methods on context (?).

Comment: Yes it's global and you can start Activity and Services from any context (Service, Application, Activity and etc.). Therefore you can't startActivityForResult from context. Actually can call it only from activity (this method defines in activity class, not in Context class). It's so, because your activityA (which calls startActivityForResult) will get result of it. It's not possible to call it from Service, for example, because Service doesn't know anything aboyt acitivity lifecycle. So, you need to call startActivityForResult on activity, not on context. Or you can call StartActivity() in ctx

Comment: @Jaś: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Comment: @Y.S http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
if(context instanceof Activity)
     (Activity(context)).startActivityForResult(..);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor for adapter

```
public YourAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

When you call it in activity

```
 adapter = new YourAdapter(YourActivity.this);
```

So you have context in your adapter.